# Create IOS App with Cordova on Windows10

Tags: ios, windows, cordova, sdk

How to make an IOS App with cordova on Windows 10? I just looked here on the official site https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide/getting-started/ios/. It says that you need an iMac! Do you realy need it? What for? Cant you just download XCode for Windows (or with emulator) and than use it to build Apps with Cordova?

Comment: why you add android tag ?

Comment: please read doc for cordova carefully, as per my knowledge you can't able to developer IOS cordova app in windows. You need XCode which is works only in MAC ios machine.

Comment: when i get it right the only problem is that I need Xcode, cant I use this with an emulator on windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FYI,
You can't install Xcode in windows. **Xcode is designed and developed by Apple specifically for mac OS X.**
It doesn't mean that you can't use Xcode on windows.
Check out below link, it should be a good starting point for you.

[Xcode on Windows](https://blog.udemy.com/xcode-on-windows/)

Hope this helps, Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 3):

those docs are really old. [Here's a link to the latest](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/).

You can create multi-platform Cordova apps under Windows, but you'll need some virtualization software (or a separate OS X box) in order to specifically add the ios and osx platforms and run them in an emulator. The same is true if you want to create the various windows platform flavors on a Macintosh -- or if you want to create the Windows / Mac platforms on a Linux box.

The Visual Studio site [has some more information](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ios/) on setup.

You can also use the [PhoneGap Build Service](https://build.phonegap.com/) to create the UWP/Android/iOS apps for you, and install them / test them directly on the appropriate devices. You can use "hydration" to push changes to the devices as you go. But I'm thinking that in the long run you might want to invest in a Mac for building / testing iOS -- it's easier to debug.